# What do mean income values in custom metric for K nearest neighbors?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to use K nearest neighbors with custom metric. I've a formula that works for properties of my objects. It means that I've matrix. This matrix consists vectors and every vector contains 3 scalar values that used in the formula.

I've found how to use custom metric within class `KNeighborsClassifier` from library sklearn. It just take a parameter called metric that can be string or callable. So... I've created function, but this function takes two same arrays contain 10 scalar values at first time. I mean every array contains 10 values instead 3. At each subsequent time the function takes values from my matrix.

I've viewed call stack and I've seen that the function called from class `BallTree`. I've read about this structure, but I can't understand how it transforms my data or what it passes to my metric at first time.

What do this two first same arrays mean?

I instantiate classifier by this code

```py
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_jobs=4, metric=custom_metric)
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

X contains values like this.

```
array([[2.400154, 0.07744107744107744, 96.80566400000001],
       [2.39325, 0.07744107744107744, 97.219544],
       [2.395162, 0.07744107744107744, 97.10519599999999],
       [3.101635, 0.009788768675940238, 65.88368],
       [3.09882, 0.009788768675940238, 65.97364499999999],
       [3.099576, 0.009788768675940238, 65.956018]], dtype=object)
```

`custom_metric` is my function. It is containing nothing right now.

```py
def custom_metric(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> float:
    pass
```

Example of `x` and `y`

```
array([ 0.02274535,  0.21161613,  0.41314247,  0.39046054,  0.1670481 ,
        0.15515555,  0.13329802,  0.59103014,  0.26246693,  0.7727967 ])
```

As I write above they are same.

Sorry if my english is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet provided does not make much sense, knn metric will never get as an argument something from different space than the one you trained it on, minimal example to show it:

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array(range(10)).reshape(5,-1)
y = np.array(range(5))

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as KNN
def foo(X, Y):
   print 'X', X, X.shape
   print 'Y', Y, Y.shape
   return 0

clf = KNN(metric=foo)
clf.fit(x, y)
clf.predict(x)
```

prints as expected

```
X [ 0.  1.] (2,)
Y [ 2.  3.] (2,)
X [ 0.  1.] (2,)
Y [ 4.  5.] (2,)
X [ 0.  1.] (2,)
Y [ 6.  7.] (2,)
X [ 0.  1.] (2,)
Y [ 8.  9.] (2,)
X [ 2.  3.] (2,)
Y [ 4.  5.] (2,)
X [ 2.  3.] (2,)
Y [ 6.  7.] (2,)
X [ 2.  3.] (2,)
Y [ 8.  9.] (2,)
X [ 4.  5.] (2,)
Y [ 6.  7.] (2,)
X [ 4.  5.] (2,)
Y [ 8.  9.] (2,)
X [ 6.  7.] (2,)
Y [ 8.  9.] (2,)
X [ 0.  1.] (2,)
Y [ 0.  1.] (2,)
X [ 2.  3.] (2,)
Y [ 2.  3.] (2,)
X [ 4.  5.] (2,)
Y [ 4.  5.] (2,)
X [ 6.  7.] (2,)
Y [ 6.  7.] (2,)
X [ 8.  9.] (2,)
Y [ 8.  9.] (2,)
```

thus in your case matric should accept 2 vectors, each 3 dimensional, and return a valid distance between them, that's all.

You can only get 10 dimensions if you pass to `predict` something with such dimensionality. There is nothing "magical" hidden in BallTree, it has to be in your data.

Comment: Hello! Can you tell me versions of your sklearn, numpy, scipy?

Comment: Oh! Do you have python 2? I'm on python 3. I've tested your code and It will output what you've showed, but on python 3 I've got an error about return value of metric function. Metric must return float value means distance between objects.

Comment: Just add return 0 at the end.  Nothing will change

Comment: I've done it already, but I meet my issue on Python 3. On Python 2 everything fine. Anyway I can do workaround. This arrays are equal so I can just return 0 ar first time. Should I mark you answer as solution?